# running hadoop .. -libjars using HIPI

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I'm new to java and trying to run a MR that uses HIPI: http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/
I've used the command as described in:
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html
I'm using hadoop 0.20.2

my command looks like: 
hadoop jar grayscalefromfile_exc.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver -libjars hipi-0.0.1.jar imgs imgsOut1

where the path looks like:

```
 --
   --grayscalefromfile_exc.jar
   --hipi-0.0.1.jar
```

The error i get:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hipi/imagebundle/mapreduce/ImageBundleInputFormat
        at grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver.run(StubDriver.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver.main(StubDriver.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hipi.imagebundle.mapreduce.ImageBundleInputFormat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 9 more

Needless to say , the hipi-0.0.1.jar, has the path inside: hipi/imagebundle/mapreduce/ImageBundleInputFormat.java

Tnx

Comment: Check my answer here, I have explained all the available options to fix this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36227260/1766402

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libjars uploads the given jars to the cluster and then makes them available on the classpath for each mapper / reducer instance

If you want to add additional jars to the driver client classpath, you'll need to use the HADOOP_CLASSPATH env variable:

```
#> export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hipi-0.0.1.jar
#> hadoop jar grayscalefromfile_exc.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver -libjars hipi-0.0.1.jar imgs imgsOut1
```

And my output when i run this (the error relates to the fact i haven't got a hipi image bundle file):

```
cswhite@Studio-1555:~/workspace/sandbox/so-hipi/target$ export $HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/cswhite/Downloads/hipi-0.0.1.jar
cswhite@Studio-1555:~/workspace/sandbox/so-hipi/target$ echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH
/home/cswhite/Downloads/hipi-0.0.1.jar
cswhite@Studio-1555:~/workspace/sandbox/so-hipi/target$ hadoop jar so-hipi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar StubDriver -libjars ~/Downloads/hipi-0.0.1.jar images output
num of args: 2:images,output
****hdfs://localhost:9000/user/cswhite/images
12/05/14 14:06:34 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/05/14 14:06:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/staging/cswhite/.staging/job_201205141351_0003
12/05/14 14:06:34 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:cswhite cause:java.io.IOException: not a hipi image bundle
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: not a hipi image bundle
    at hipi.imagebundle.HipiImageBundle.readBundleHeader(HipiImageBundle.java:322)
    at hipi.imagebundle.HipiImageBundle.openForRead(HipiImageBundle.java:388)
    at hipi.imagebundle.AbstractImageBundle.open(AbstractImageBundle.java:82)
    at hipi.imagebundle.AbstractImageBundle.open(AbstractImageBundle.java:55)
    at hipi.imagebundle.mapreduce.ImageBundleInputFormat.getSplits(ImageBundleInputFormat.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:979)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:530)
    at StubDriver.run(StubDriver.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at StubDriver.main(StubDriver.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked :)
Could you please also refer me to where you saw the "export" command for this procedure ? (didn't find it in the hadoop -libjars ref).

Comment: It ran, but gave the same error: 
hadoop jar grayscalefromfile_exc.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver imgs/imgs.hib imgsOut1
12/05/06 13:01:37 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
1 tasks spawned
12/05/06 13:01:38 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201205060330_0002
12/05/06 13:01:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/05/06 13:01:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201205060330_0002_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hipi.imagebundle.mapreduce.ImageBundleInputFormat
        at

Comment: try setting HADOOP_CLASSPATH to the fully qualified path of the jar, e.g: `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/home/myuser/hipi-0.0.1.jar`

Comment: hey, i tried, same error. Here is the full output of both tries: http://pastebin.com/5A4rXHiZ 
I just want to run it... :/

Comment: It might be the order arguments are being consumed, try putting the libjars portion before the main jar: `hadoop jar -libjars hipi-0.0.1.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver imgs/imgs.hib imgsOut1`

Comment: NOPE :(
jar -libjars hipi-0.0.1.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver imgs/imgs.hib imgsOut1
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error opening job jar: -libjars
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:124)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main

Comment: Can you post line 89 from your StubDriver.java? (the line where you're configuring the `job.setInputFormat(...)`)

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/cbTQFezU here is the full driver. Tnx for helping, much appreciated

Comment: Right, but you must specifiy a .hib file. So after creating a hib file, and running: hadoop jar grayscalefromfile_exc.jar grayscalefromfile_exc.StubDriver -libjars hipi-0.0.1.jar imgs/imgs.hib imgsOut1


you'll get me error.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve a similar issue by using the following API in the main class

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/path/application.jar"), conf);
```

The jar must be present in hdfs path `/path/application.jar`.

Comment: Hey, tnx for your answer. It still didn't work, failed on the same error. I honestly don't knwo.. :/ 

I've tried using it only with hipi library