# ClassNotFoundException error in running Hadoop jar file

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I am getting the following error running a hadoop jar file

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hdfs:
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)

Comment: What command are you running which generates this exception?

Comment: The command that i am using is hadoop jar june1wordcount.jar wordcountproblem /input /output

Comment: Check my answer here, I have explained all the available options to fix this issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36227260/1766402

Answer (score 0):

The jar file that you want to run must be the actual path in your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Add the hdfs jar file in your build path or pom.xml file